# Selenium Grid: Not able to create Gecko Driver Session

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I tried to execute selenium grid on my MS Windows pc but shows up exception like below:

> INFO: Exception: Unable to create new service: GeckoDriverService

Why caused this error? How to solve this problem?

```
 Hub
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role hub

 Node
 java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role node -hub 
 http://localhost:4444/grid/register
```

Comment: May be you didn't added the gecko driver executable in the environment variables.

Comment: Please add the code you're using to create the web driver, the Grid hub, and the Grid node

Comment: How to add gecko driver environment variables on Ms Windows?

Comment: Problem solved.